# Class Init with Optional Parameters - not possible?

Tags: swift

Can someone help me understand why I am unable to set the the middleName parameter to a value? I have declared it as an optional, but whenever I try to initialize it, I always get nil running through the guard statement in the `getFullName()` function.

```
var firstName: String
var middleName: String?
var lastName: String

init(firstName: String, middleName: String, lastName: String)
{
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.middleName? = middleName
    self.lastName = lastName
}

func getFullName() -> String
{        
    guard let midName = self.middleName else
    {
        return "\(firstName) \(lastName)"
    }

    return "\(firstName) \(midName) \(lastName)"
}

let person = Person(firstName: "Foo", middleName: "Bar", lastName: "FooBar")
```

The returned value when printed is "Foo Foobar". Why is that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need (or want) to unwrap the property when you are assigning to it.  You just refer to it directly;

```
init(firstName: String, middleName: String, lastName: String)
{
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.middleName = middleName
    self.lastName = lastName
}
```

When `middleName` is `nil` (as it is initially) the conditional unwrap `self.middleName?` fails, so the assignment isn't performed.

Conditionally unwrapping `self.middleName` is effectively a shorthand way of saying

```
if self.middleName != nil {
    self.middleName = middleName
}
```

Since `middleName` is optional, then you may want to make the initialisation parameter optional too:

```
init(firstName: String, middleName: String?=nil, lastName: String)
{
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.middleName = middleName
    self.lastName = lastName
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Quick question: When you say that "You just reference it", what exactly do you mean by "it"? Do you mean that the property `self.middleName` reference the `middleName` parameter (the "it" part)?

Comment: "It" being the property `middleName`.  You don't need the ?.  With the ? you are accessing the value of the property, not the property.

Comment: Sorry, I might be confusing myself. This is quite new to me. So, `middleName` as in before the assignment or after?

Comment: `self.middleName` is a property.  When you say `self.middleName?` you are saying to Swift "Conditionally unwrap `self.middleName`" - Conditionally unwrapping is a shorthand way of saying `if self.middleName != nil { self.middleName=middleName }`

Comment: Oh.. of course. The middleName in the enclosing parenthesis is a parameter whereas the other is a property. I was right about confusing myself. Thank you so much for clarifying your answer. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

If a property is optional you have to make the corresponding parameter in the `init` method optional, too, otherwise it's pointless to declare the property as optional.

```
init(firstName: String, middleName: String?, lastName: String)
{
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.middleName = middleName
    self.lastName = lastName
}
```

You can even assign `nil` as default *value* to be able to omit the parameter

```
init(firstName: String, middleName: String? = nil, lastName: String)
{
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.middleName = middleName
    self.lastName = lastName
}

let person = Person(firstName: "Foo", lastName: "FooBar")
```

Comment: Oh wauw.. but why would it throw an error if the line `self.middleName` is an optional?

Comment: See the explanation in Paulw11's answer.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Thank you :D